# Logging in Spring Boot-docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I need a solution to write logs of every microservices(spring boot) into a separate log file.The services have deployed in docker containers and if I write logs into the docker context,when docker restarts logs get disappear.can I write logs into docker engine.

Comment: Instead of trying to keep the log files around between docker restarts, I would suggest using a service like AWS CloudWatch Logs to stream the logs to a central location that exists outside the Docker context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use volumes. Volumes are shared between host-container and persistent.

According to the documentation:

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by
>   and used by Docker containers

You can easily follow the documentation to know how volume works and how to use it - https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

So, the steps will be as below -

- Create  a directory to keep log files on the host machine
- Use the directory as a shared volume between host and container. You can specify it when you run the container.
- From the container write log files to that directory